# Get image ids in a div every second

Tags: javascript

I was successful in getting the id of all images within a div when clicking the div with the following codes below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getimgid(){
var elems = [].slice.call( document.getElementById("card") );
elems.forEach( function( elem ){
elem.onclick = function(){
    var arr = [], imgs = [].slice.call( elem.getElementsByTagName("img") );
    if(imgs.length){
        imgs.forEach( function( img ){
            var attrID = img.id;
            arr.push(attrID);
        alert(arr);
        });
    } else {
        alert("No images found.");
    }
};
});
}
</script>
```

The codes above works perfectly, doing an alert message of the image id when clicking **card** div. Now what I want is to run this function without clicking the div in every 5 seconds. I have tried **setInterval (getimgid, 5000)**, but it doesn't work. Which part of the codes above should I modify to call the function without clicking the div. Any help would  be much appreciated.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dx4w)

Comment: where in this code are you calling your php?

Comment: Do you want to trigger click every 5 seconds?

Comment: the problem is that you are not triggering the click in setInterval. you are only re-running the event binding every 5 secs.

Comment: I have set that the div has no click events . When the page loads function getimgid() is called every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use elem.click() to trigger click

```
function getimgid() {
    var elems = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("card"));
    elems.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.onclick = function () {
            var arr = [],
                imgs = [].slice.call(elem.getElementsByTagName("img"));
            if (imgs.length) {
                imgs.forEach(function (img) {
                    var attrID = img.id;
                    arr.push(attrID);
                    alert(arr);
                });
            } else {
                alert("No images found.");
            }
        };
        elem.click();
    });
}
setInterval(getimgid, 1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dx4w/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling it this way:

```
setInterval (function(){
getimgid();
},5000);
```

also remove binding of click event for element.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dx4w/1/)**

Comment: it should be `getimgid()` for calling function.

Comment: no errors, I guess the part **elem.onclick** must be modified or removed, but everytime i do it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @ClydeWinux:would be great if you can create the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

*Problem*: You are not triggering the click in `setInterval`. You are only re-running the event binding every 5 secs.

*Solution*: Set Interval on another function which triggers the click. Or remove the `click` binding altogether if you don't want to manually click at all.

*Updated fiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3Dx4w/5/

*JS*:

```
var t;

function trigger() {
        var elems = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("card"));
    elems.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.onclick();
    });
}

t = setInterval(trigger, 5000);
```